C# Textblock inline, how to access different elements?
I am using Textblock.Inlines to add a picture and text to a header element. Without going too deep into the code, this is a short example.
TextBlock tbHeader = new TextBlock();
Image headerImage = new Image();
var bitmapImage = new BitmapImage(<image loading here>);
headerImage.Source = bitmapImage;

tbHeader.Inlines.Add(headerImage);
tbHeader.Inlines.Add("   " + text);

example.Header = tbHeader

The textblock works as expected, and the image is then followed by text. However, because the header is now a TextBlock element with an InlinesCollection, I can't simply access the text side of this.
How do I go about accessing specifically the text after the image in the text block?
I'm not familiar with how InlineCollections` work or how to go through to find a specific one I need.

You could use the Tag property to store the information you wish to receive easily.

Tag : Gets or sets an arbitrary object value that can be used to store custom information about this element.
(Inherited from FrameworkElement)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.frameworkelement.tag?view=windowsdesktop-8.0#system-windows-frameworkelement-tag
TextBlock tbHeader = new TextBlock();
Image headerImage = new Image();
var bitmapImage = new BitmapImage(<image loading here>);
headerImage.Source = bitmapImage;

tbHeader.Inlines.Add(headerImage);
tbHeader.Inlines.Add("   " + text);
tbHeader.Tag = text;

example.Header = tbHeader

Retrieval is as simple as
example.Header.Tag.ToString();

